# Firebase and localization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working in app that support Arabic and English language using firebase database my question is there is any way I can localize data that come from firebase in my my app

Comment: Try https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities
It cache the data to local web storages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is there is any way I can localize data that come from firebase in my app?

There are many ways in which you can locate a user, but this requires enabling the device's location, asking for permissions, and so on. This option might not be the best one, because I, as a traveler, if I visit your country and download your app, I'll get Arabic content and I won't be happy with that, because I don't know Arabic. The best option that you have is to display the content according to the language the user has already set on the device. So it doesn't matter where the user is localized, the user will always see the content in the language he likes. For example, if a user from your country will travel to the United States, he will still see the content of your app in Arabic, which makes sense, because it's possible that the user might not know English.

Another option might be to let the user choose the language even from the beginning when first time opens the app. That way, you'll always be sure about the preferred language. However, don't forget to add the option to update this preference later, if needed.

Comment: thank you @Alex what is confused me about localization is I'm only able to localize UI so what about what I get from firebase and I want to display it to users

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "localize UI". Regarding Firebase, if you have some data in your Realtime Database, you can display it in the way you want. If you have a hard time implementing, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.